# What is the smallest version base on Semantic Versioning 2.0.0?

Tags: semantic-versioning

What is the smallest version base on Semantic Versioning 2.0.0?

Semantic Versioning 2.0.0: https://semver.org/

https://go.dev/ref/mod go mod force me to use Semantic Versioning 2.0.0 as git tag. And I need to make sure my version is increase. I just commit my library first time, so I think I should use the smallest version as first version.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my test the smallest version is v0.0.0-0 . No biggest version when string length is unlimited.

Here is my test base on some example:

https://gist.github.com/bronze1man/90aad9f41692c16895be3e499021dc73

- valid (sort by smallest to biggest)

```
v0.0.0-0
v0.0.0-0+0
v0.0.0-2
v0.0.0-12
v0.0.0--0
v0.0.0-12alpha
v0.0.0-alpha
v0.0.0-alpha12
v0.0.0+0
v0.0.0
v0.0
v0
v0.0.1-0
v0.0.1-0.0
v0.0.1-0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1
v0.0.1-0.0.0.1
v0.0.1-0.0.1
v0.0.1-0.1
v0.0.1-1
v0.0.1-a
v0.0.1-alpha
v0.0.1
v0.0.2
v0.0.12
v1.0.0-0
v1
v1.0
v1.0.0
v2.0.0
v12.0.0
v99999999999999999999999999999999.0.0
```

- invalid

```
v0.0.0.1
v0.0.0-000
v0.0.0-002
v0.0.0+
v0.0.0-
v0-0
v1-0
```